# Undo dismissed creations in Google Photos

Tags: google-photos

Google Photos' Auto-awesome has now changed to 'Creations'. Back when it was auto-awesome, the auto-awesome, whether it be a video, story or a photo with a cool effect applied, would always be saved in my Google Photos and if I ever wanted to view them, I could click on Auto-awesome within Google Photos.

However, now, under the new 'Creations' title, they are presented in my phone as a type of Google Now card that can be swiped away, or, dismissed.

I have already dismissed many of Google Photo Stories which were automatically generated because I assumed that I was basically being notified that they were ready to view in Photos. I also attempted to press the SAVE TO LIBRARY bar at the bottom of the swipe card and this actually doesn't do anything.

Is it possible to undo all of these dismissed Creations? They are not in the bin either.

Background information on Creations: https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6128811?hl=en

Comment: This question belongs on [WebApps.SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When accessing from web version, in the bottom part of the assistant page, there is a link to discarded creations. You have to scroll down the page.